# menu border line

Tags: html, css, menu, border

There is no border line at the end of last element in the menu. I cannot fix it. Could you please help? Thanks for any help.

```
 div.menu { 
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#FBB117;} 
 div.menu ul{ 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size:14px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 100px 
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;} 
 div.menu li{ 
    display:inline; } 
 div.menu li a{ 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:7px 0; 
    width:100px; 
    background:#FBB117; 
    color:#4C4646; 
    float:left; 
    text-align:center; 
    border-left:1px solid #fff;}  
 div.menu li a:hover{ 
    background:#a2b3a1; 
    color:#000 }
```

Comment: Did you try jsfiddle for fixing up? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You're only using a border-left. When you look at you menu, and you see that things have a right border, it's actually just the left border from the next element. There is no next element on the last item.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to add a border for the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do this easily as like this

used last child and give to li border left

My code is

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home2</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home3</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home4</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home5</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div.menu { 
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0; 
    width:70%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#FBB117;
    overflow:hidden;
} 
 div.menu ul{ 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 3px;
    width: 100%; 
    padding:0;

  } 
 div.menu li{ 
    margin:10px 0;  
    float:left; 
    border-left:1px solid #fff; 
} 
 div.menu li a{ 
    text-decoration:none; 
    line-height:29px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background:#FBB117; 
    color:#4C4646; 
    text-align:center;
display:inline-block; 


   }
div.menu li:last-child{
    border-right:solid 1px #fff;
}
 div.menu li a:hover{ 
    background:#a2b3a1; 
    color:#000 } 


​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/aJ5hc/

more info about Pseudo Classes http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but the mneu is not centered anymore and also menu line thicker and is not 100% width anymore. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    div.menu li{
          border-right: 1px solid #fff;
          display:inline-block;
        }    
    div.menu li:last-child{
          border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        }
```

put the border right out of the links and put it in the li

Comment: But end borders are thinner than others.

Comment: At least when I open it, FF11 ignores the `:last-child` and simply applies it to all elements. That creates a seeming 2px border inbetween elements because there is no margin between left and right borders of neighbouring `li`. The first and last one are correctly only 1px - that's what he means I think.

Comment: edited. haven't thought about it. every a is the last child of the li. so the borders must run over the li's

Comment: Yes it does; he just didn't amend his code properly. [Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tTwDF/2/). Bear in mind I removed the css for the `div.menu` element, to reduce the visual clutter.

Comment: are you this is the answer of my question?